# Simple Magento2 example of retrieving and displaying a custom table field?

Tags: magento2, database, custom, fieldsets

I have a custom table in my Magento2 database and can not find a simple *working* example of how to connect, retrieve, and display the field data in a Magento2 page.

This one mostly works but is incomplete because it stops at fetching the field but doesn't show how to actually display the field on the webpage:
http://webkul.com/blog/magento2-write-custom-mysql-query-without-using-model/

Can someone please provide a complete example?

Comment: For Magento 2. I'm using below CRUD generator https://mage2gen.com/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have mentioned a tutorial that explains CRUD operation without a model, but it is not good practice using object manager.

let me explain the crud operation with the model, it is very simple. This is a very important concept in Magento.

For example, Let's consider the below table structure

[image]

For CRUD operation you need to create three things

**1. Model**

In Model, you need to initialize the resource model

`app/code/<vendor>/<module>/Model/Example.php`

```
<?php
namespace <vendor>\<module>\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
class Example extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
    $this->_init('<vendor>\<module>\Model\ResourceModel\Example');
    }
}
```

**2. Resource Model**

In the Resource model, you need to initialize the table name and primary key.

`app/code/<vendor>/<module>/Model/ResourceModel/Example.php`

```
<?php
namespace <vendor>\<module>\Model\Resource;
class Example extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Define the main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
    $this->_init('custom_table_name', 'id');   //here id is the primary key of custom table
    }
}
```

**3. Collection**

In the collection, you need to define the Model and Resource Model.

`app/code/<vendor>/<module>/Model/ResourceModel/Example/Collection.php`

```
<?php
namespace <vendor>\<module>\Model\ResourceModel\Example;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
    $this->_init(
        '<vendor>\<module>\Model\Example',
        '<vendor>\<module>\Model\ResourceModel\Example'
    );
    
    }
}
```

That's it, now you can able to fetch table values in any block using dependency injection.

For eg:
**Get and Set Data in Block**

Kindly note, we pass  `<module>\<vendor>\Model\ExampleFactory` in the constructor, but none of the files will be found in that location

In Magento 2, each CRUD model has a corresponding factory class. All factory class names are the name of the model class appended with the word “Factory”.Since our model class is named
`<module>/<vendor>/Model/Example` this means our factory class is named `<module>/<vendor>/Model/ExampleFactory`

```
………………….
………………….

protected $_exampleFactory; 

public function __construct( <vendor>\<module>\Model\ExampleFactory $db)
{
    $this->_exampleFactory = $db;
}
public function anyMethodYouWant()
{
//set value
$this->_exampleFactory->create()->setData(array('event_name' => 'xyz', 'event_imgurl' => 'xyz',...............))->save();

//get value
$data=$this->_exampleFactory->create()->getCollection();
foreach ($data as $d ) 
{
       echo $d->getEventImgurl();   //table field event_imgurl
       echo $d->getEventName();    //table field event_name
}

}
```

after that, you can call this block method in your template file

```
<?php $block->anyMethodYouWant(); ?>
```

Comment: @Bilal -  (where I have to write this code I mean pls give path)

protected $_exampleFactory; 
public function __construct( <vendor>/<module>/Model/ExampleFactory $db)
{
    $this->_exampleFactory = $db;
}
public function anyMethodYouWant()
{
$this->_exampleFactory->create()->setData(array('event_name' => 'xyz', 'event_imgurl' => 'xyz',...............))->save();
$data=$this->_exampleFactory->create()->getCollection();
foreach ($data as $d ) 
{
       echo $d->getEventImgurl();  
       echo $d->getEventName();   
}
}

Comment: Well Explain @BilalUsean . :)

Comment: Finally I found a simple and easy explanation for doing models on Magento2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Very simple to follow and the explanations about the default existing Factory in Magento 2 is a life saver. Just couldn't find anything clear about it. Have been struggling for months trying to figure out how to work with Magento 2, your answer helps me unblock some points and move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the last piece. Sorry. The last code snippet I have to put in a directory "Block"? And how should I call it?
The call block I put is in an HTML file, but I get an error?
Please support?